# How to concatenate kubernetes jobs?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a chain process. When a parent's job ends, a child (or multiple children) job starts. The main problem is that I want to have only the current job pods deployed.

Something like: job1 starts --> job 1 finish --> job 2 starts --> job 2 finish --> job 3 starts --> job 3 finish.

How can I do this? I thought that I could create in disabled mode job 1, job 2, and job 3 at the same time and enable them when the respective parent job ends (maybe with a service?).

I recently read about a tool called [argo-workflow](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows) but I am not sure if it will do the chain effect that I am searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. CI/CD solution like Argo workflow is the way to go. You can check this example on how to execute different task one by one using `steps` [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/examples/#steps).